# On tangents of parabolas

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

**Question**

Let $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ be constants. Suppose that the parabolas $$C_1 : y^2 = 4a(a - x)\ \mathrm {and}\ C_2 : y^2 = 4b(b + x)$$ intersect at a point $P$. Prove that the tangent line to $C_1$ at $P$ and the tangent line to $C_2$ at $P$ are perpendicular.

---

**My Working**

From $C_1$,

$$2y\frac {dy} {dx} = -4a$$

$$\implies \frac {dy} {dx} = -\frac {2a} {y}$$

From $C_2$,

$$2y\frac {dy} {dx} = 4b$$

$$\implies \frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {2b} {y}$$

Then, from elementary geometry, I know that for two lines to be perpendicular to each other, the product of their gradients must be $-1$.

Thus, working backwards,

$$(-\frac {2a} {y})(\frac {2b} {y}) = -1$$

$$\implies y^2 = 4ab$$

so the problem reduces to showing that $$y^2 = 4ab$$

and we are done.

---

However, this is where I am stuck. How do I show the above relation given only the equations of the two curves?

Any suggestions to how I may proceed or even alternatives to solving this problem will be nice :)

Comment: Hint: find the $x$ coordinates of the point of intersection.

Comment: Oh. I never thought about the problem that far. My brain really does not work under test conditions. Indeed, the solution is so trivial and I have solved it. Thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think important to say that this is the tip of an iceberg.

I extract this illustration

[image]

*Family $C_a$: the red curves. Family $C_b$: the blue curves. They can be considered as the images of the rectangular grid on the left by a so-called "conformal mapping".*

from this [excellent document](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ejorloff/18.04/notes/topic10.pdf), showing we are in a particular case of **conformal mapping**, meaning the image of an orthogonal network (here, horizontal et vertical lines) by a derivable function $Z=f(z)$ with $z,Z \in \mathbb{C}$ (here $f(z)=z^2$ "bending" all straight lines into parabolas) while preserving orthogonality.